# Git merge strategies vs. merge drivers vs. mergetools

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

Both Stack Overflow answers, and various webpages, give contradictory or conflicting definitions of "merge strategy", "merge driver", and "mergetool".
Here is my best understanding of them.

- **merge strategy**: called on every file that is merged; however, if two of {parent1,parent2,base} are the same, then the "low-level merge driver" (i.e., `git merge-file`) is never called.
  The merge strategy is responsible for detecting and handling renames.
  A merge strategy is [hard to write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47454227/how-to-configure-a-merge-strategy).
  If you have a `git-merge-xyz` in your path then git will run it if you `git merge --strategy xyz`.
  The `git-merge-xyz` programs that come with git are just links to the git executable itself.
  You can supply multiple strategies:  git merge will take the first that succeeds (0 exit status) or will heuristically choose among the strategies whose exit status is 1.
  When writing a merge strategy use `GIT_TRACE=1 git merge -s <strategy>` to see the command-line arguments passed to it.  There are also environment variables that have effects.
- **merge driver**:  called automatically when there is a difference in file content (no two of {base,parent1,parent2} are the same).
  It is run once per file with a conflict.  It is run on temporary files, but you can get the path of the conflicting file using the %P parameter.
  It observes the original version of the parent and base files.
  It overwrites its input named `%A` with the merge result, which may contain conflict markers.
  You can use Git attributes to use different merge strategies for files whose names match given patterns.
- **mergetool** (merge tool):  never run automatically.  If a user runs `git mergetool`,
  the mergetool is run on all conflicted files (one at a time) and observes the conflict markers.
  It gets the names of the original files.

A git mergetool is not invoked on files that contain no merge conflict.
It assumes that if the git merge strategy didn't output a merge conflict, then the merge was correct.
This means that a git mergetool will never reduce the number of clean-but-incorrect merges.  It will only change some conflicted merges into correct or incorrect merges.

A git merge driver is never called if two of {base,parent1,parent2} are the same.

My question is:  are the above definitions and facts correct?  Do they omit any important information?

Comment: I don't know about the little details _but_ I do know that each strategy is not called **per file**. It's the opposite. Strategies will be called one after the other to see if they can solve the whole merge.

Comment: @eftshift0 Right.  A merge strategy is called all at once, and a merge driver or mergetool is called per file.