# Git custom merge driver with fallback to the built-in driver

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I have a custom merge driver for a type of text file with a specific layout. (It solves basically the same problem as `git-merge-changelog`: when things are added at the same place, I have rules to decide in in what order to put them.)

This merge driver is based on heuristics and sometimes fails when the changes are too complex. When it fails, I want to fall back to git's default handling of text files.

I've set up `.gitattributes`:

```
myfile merge=my-driver
```

and `.gitconfig`:

```
[merge "my-driver"]
    name = My merge driver for myfile
    driver = my-merge-driver %O %A %B
```

This is fine when my custom merge driver is able to resolve the conflicts. When the driver program can't resolve the conflicts, it returns a non-zero code and doesn't modify `%A`. This causes git to report a conflict (good), but to leave the current version of the file in place. Instead, I want git to run the built-in text merge driver.

How can I use my custom merge driver, but if it fails, use the built-in driver as a fallback?

Answer (score 4):

A partial solution (at least for a “normal”, two-way merge):

```
driver = my-merge-driver %O %A %B || git-merge-file -q --marker-size=%L %A %O %B
```

This works in that it performs a text merge and produces conflict markers. Unfortunately, the conflict markers have temporary file names (`<<<<<<< .merge_file_xxxxxx`) instead of branch names. I'd prefer to have the branch names.

This may be resolved in the same way as [How to retrieve branch names in a custom Git merge driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302644/how-to-retrieve-branch-names-in-a-custom-git-merge-driver) (currently unanswered).

Comment: That's the right way. It's not documented and it has a pitfall if you're running an octopus merge, because then there will be multiple environment variables, one for each head. I'll answer that other question too, I guess.

Comment: You can have a bit better looking names by using it like `git merge-file -L "current" -L "base" -L "incoming" --marker-size=%L %A %O %B`.